# Telegram bot that sends scheduled messages and saves my reply in a database or google docs sheet

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I am learning coding at the moment and this is my first Interaction with Stackoverflow except reading stuff.

I would like to connect to a telegram bot and want it to send me a message how i feel on a scale from 1-10. So my messages should only be integers. I want to save my replies with the date and the value to get a weekly or monthly average.

Like I said I am a beginner and would love to hear your suggestions or maybe other solutions that would suit to my case.

Thank you in advance !

I would like to write it in C# or Javascript.
I was thinking about using a nosql DB - Do you think thats suited for the project?
Else i could also use Excel table or google sheets.

Comment: This question is to broad to answer, but yea that wouldn't be that difficult to make, I'd suggest to start with an example bot in a language of your liking and then extend the functions one by one, if you get stuck you can ask another question with some code so we can help.